# Reference link not seeming to connect to CSS

Tags: html, css

If my directory is set up like this:

```
projectfolder/
   wsgi/
     openshift/
         templates/
            home/
              simple-sidebar.html
     static/
         css/
            bootstrap.css
         fonts/
         js/
```

Why does my simple-sidebar.html reference link not work?:

```
<link href= "../../../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't forget to add `type="text/css"` to your `<link>`!

Comment: It depends on actual URL of the simple-sidebar.html, not the project folders structure.

Comment: What do you mean? I am going to be hosting it online, does this make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
<link href= "/wsig/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is absolute url.

If you want it your way, you have to do this:

```
<link href= "../../../../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, what do you mean to say?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside the `home` folder ,

this should work ,

```
<link href= "/wsig/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Remember,

```
/  - denotes the current directory you are in 
./ - one step outside the current directory   
../ - two steps outside the directory
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

this might be help you.

```
<link href= "../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```